# PyQt5: How to dynamically populate a Qt Window with labels and text input fields

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-creator, qt-designer

I am creating a basic testing tool for an API, with the following primitive design:

[image]

Whenever the combo box is changed, the fields "Test Input" and "Expected Output" should be populated with the labels and input text fields of the related data call. Each data call has different input and output parameters, therefore I cannot create static input fields. I have a mapping for each data call and related input-output parameters. How can I use this mapping to dynamically create labels and text input fields on the UI?

Edit: I could manage how to dynamically populate the UI based on my mapping. It works now for the initial setting of the combo box, but when I change the combo box, UI is not affected. I think I should clear the QScrollArea on each change, but I couldn't manage how to do so.

```
self.input_scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.centralwidget)
self.input_scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
self.input_scrollArea.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 90, 311, 311))
self.input_scrollArea.setObjectName("input_scrollArea")
self.input_scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
self.input_scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 309, 309))
self.input_scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("input_scrollAreaWidgetContents")
self.input_scrollArea.setWidget(self.input_scrollAreaWidgetContents)

def on_combobox_data_call_changed(self, combobox_index):
    data_call_name = list(DATA_CALL_MAP.keys())[combobox_index]
    y_pos = 40
    for param in DATA_CALL_MAP[data_call_name]["required_params"]:
        exec(f"self.label_{param} = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.input_scrollAreaWidgetContents)")
        exec(f"self.label_{param}.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, {y_pos}, 125, 21))")
        exec(f"self.label_{param}.setObjectName(\"label_{param}\")")
        exec(f"self.label_{param}.setText(_translate(\"TestCaseWindow\", \"{param}:\"))")
        exec(f"self.input_{param} = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.input_scrollAreaWidgetContents)")
        exec(f"self.input_{param}.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, {y_pos}, 125, 21))")
        exec(f"self.input_{param}.setObjectName(\"input_{param}\")")
        y_pos += 40
```

Comment: You cannot do this from Designer, and it should all be done by code, for which you may have multiple solutions depending on your specific needs (which we don't know). Perhaps a basic [QFormLayout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qformlayout.html) that repopulates itself for each call, possibly by using a subclass to simplify things. Note that if the field number can vary and be high, you should probably use a QScrollArea. Other than that, it's not possible to provide you a proper answer, as your question is too broad and there are dozens of possible alternative (and valid) approaches.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment @musicamante ! Could you please have a look at my edit?

Comment: 1. do not use `exec()` for that; never, **ever**; 2. if you want to set instance attributes, use [`setattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr); 3. I'm not completely sure, but I'm under the impression that you're trying to edit the code generated by pyuic; if that's the case, be aware that it's considered a **bad** practice, as those files should ***always*** be used as imports without **any** modification; please read the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).